# Group_by months in R

Tags: r, group-by

This is my first question on stackoverflow so please correct me if the question is unclear.

I've been trying to group the months of each year together, however I keep receiving this error.

```
Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `month = lubridate::floor_date(Date, "month")`.
Caused by error in `object[[name, exact = TRUE]]`:
! object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Code:

```
#Group each month together 

combined_months <- combined_data %>% 
  group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(Date, 'month')) %>%
  summarize(pip_count = sum(sum_of_pip_difference))
```

Table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70JG8.png)

Comment: In your screenshot of data, you do not have a column called `Date`. You need to use `floor_date` on a column. `Date` is also the name of a function, which leads to the error (functions are "objects of type closure", and the `floor_date` function subsets its input, hence the error).

Comment: Looks like your column is named `month`, so you could use `group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(month, 'month'))`. But it also looks like your `month` column is already floored, so you might not need it at all.